# how to read and parse through an excel file using spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

Is there any way to read and parse an excel(.XLS) file using **Spring Batch**? For .csv file reader and mappers are there, but i am struggling with .xls file as input file.
Any Suggestions !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cream a custom item reader using apache poi.
or use a custom poitasklet to extract the data to files, then use the basic csv readers

Comment: I wrote customized reader and its working fine..thanks